# Auto-respond to Android Phone Call and Send Tone

Tags: android, automation, phone

I'd like to automatically accept calls from a certain number, send a series of tones (e.g. 1234#), and then hang up.

Is there an app or Android feature which can accomplish this? It can require root, but it should be able to accept the call, send the tones, and hang up without opening a foreground app.